# ctrl+alt+f7 can't switch

Tags: linux, gui, text-user-interface

In my debian8 terminal.

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

Now reboot to text mode,to input **startx** to enter into gui mode.

To press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>f7</kbd>,nothing happen.
 <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>f1-f6</kbd>  can switch each other.
It seems that <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>f7</kbd> baned.

Comment: This probably provides enough information to answer. However, it would be nice if you said why you expected ctrl+alt+f7 would work. (Or even what you expected it would do - you didn't say).

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, starting X always automatically switches, to the Virtual Terminal which that X server uses.  It is never necessary to manually switch to the VT as part of starting X.

On Debian 8 with systemd, you should find that X is started on the next free VT.  If you are logged in to tty1, and you have not yet switched to tty2, tty2 would have been free.[*]  (ctrl+alt+F2).

The reason ctrl+alt+f7 did absolutely nothing, is that VT7 was completely unused.  It's just what happens, if you try to switch to a VT which is completely unused.

If you're not sure, I think you can use root privileges (e.g. sudo) to find which number VT the X server is using.  Find the Process ID of X with `pgrep X` e.g. 100, then `sudo lsof -p 100`.  Or the other way around: `sudo lsof /dev/tty[0-9]*`

---

On a more up-to-date system like Fedora Linux, you should find X runs on the *same* VT that `startx` was run from.  The X server is unable to grab or switch VTs, because it no longer runs as `root`.

[*]  Systemd behaves differently to the previous init system: it only runs a text login prompt on a VT (VT1 to VT6) when you actually switch to it.  Before systemd, login prompts were started on all 6 VTs at boot time.  Hence leaving VT7 to run X on (ctrl+alt+f7).  (Also, it's possible to free up a VT again with `sudo systemctl stop getty@tty2` :).

Comment: systemd does not behave differently to the previous init system if one was using Fedora.  [The Fedora virtual terminal change happened in 2008](https://lwn.net/Articles/305774/), with upstart, before systemd existed.

Comment: note: on X you press `Control-Alt-Fx`, but on terminal just `Alt-Fx`.